# c# Unicode Null Representation code character array

Tags: c#, unicode

I am creating a character array.Is there a unicode code for null? For example if I need to put a null in the character array?And also when I use the unicode table https://unicode-table.com/en/#myanmar which is the code I should use since there is HTML-code,Unicode number... I'm confused.

```
char[] specialSymb= new char[] { ' ', ',', '.','?','!'};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Microsoft's documentation on Character literals (Which is what you are asking for) these are the following types of **null** encoding:

**Escape sequence**

```
\0
```

**Unicode encoding**

```
0x0000
```

EDIT:

**For HTML Unicodes**

```
%00
```

or

```
&#0;
```

Source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691087(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: can you answer "which is the code I should use since there is HTML-code,Unicode number" this too ?:D